# Rails app generating MySQL load though now database access triggered

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4.x application running on server A and MySQL on server B.

Using ab to do a load test of my API calls I notice that the MySQL server is showing CPU activity. So I go back to the code and check, but no SQL statements are triggered, to be sure I also deactivate all before filters, but still the MySQL server shows CPU load.

I went to MySQL and run

```
show processlist;
```

but that also shows no active SQL statements

Why would there be load on the DB server?

Comment: What does top say? Is it really mysql pegging your cpu or is it something else?

Comment: top says that mysqld is using CPU, 2% to 5% when I push lots of requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rails application initializes connection pools to the configured database on app load and also loads basic schema data for each ActiveModel defined to populate runtime mappings from the DB to instances of that model.

These connections/queries will happen as soon as you have loaded the application and running traffic.

If this is not what is responsible for the activity on your database server, you will need to use other tools to see what is responsible.  For example, NewRelic's system monitoring tools are great for snapshotting CPU/memory usage over time correlated to what processes were running.  This will help you rule out MySQL itself using resources vs. other things running on the DB server.

Comment: Yes, but these initializations happen during application startup, don't they? Or are you saying they happen every time there is a page hit?

Comment: Your app server will be making/establishing connections over time if you are processing requests.  On the server side, maintaining those connections will trigger some minimal activity.  I don't understand what your concern is.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/17/mysql-server-memory-usage/), storage engines like Innodb may have their own per thread and/or global memory allocations which is probably accounting for the CPU overhead. If this is a stock (non-tuned) MySql install, you're probably just seeing baseline CPU activity. The article mentions a number of places to look that might indicate areas that can be tuned to reduce this footprint.